# Yesterday's birthdays on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Is there an easy way to view birthdays that occurred in the recent past on Facebook? Right now, the only method I know of is to scan forward to next year, minus a day.

Comment: Scroll back through the News Feed and look for messages that say "Thank you, everyone, for the wonderful birthday wishes!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use link address to go to view birthdays that occurred in the recent past on Facebook. http://facebook.com/?sk=bd&s=-1

Comment: You win three internets!

Comment: not working any more.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the only way to check the recent past, is to go to the future. Navigate to the last page and you'll find what you're looking for.

Comment: Sadly this is the only answer. I suggested to FB that they allow going back a week too...

Answer (score 1):

To see Facebook Birthdays go to Events and select [Birthdays](https://www.facebook.com/events/birthdays/) where the link is

> https://www.facebook.com/events/birthdays/

Or on the homepage on the right you should see [image: Birthday on the right of the homepage]

On arriving on this page you should have birthdays separated by

- Today
- This week
- This month

Scroll to the bottom, there you will see you are given two options

> Past Events · Export Birthdays

But in fact, there are four options.

[image: Two options with two subtle options]

You see the <kbd>◀</kbd> (left) and <kbd>▶</kbd> (right) arrows?

The left ▶ arrow  should take you go back to the previous section of the current month as well as the preceding month.